# GWT - Double to Long results in wrong number

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm not sure if this is a bug, if I just hit a limitation of GWT or if I'm just stupid creating a double with such high number.

When doing the following on the client side:

```
Double d = 10152826455075087d;
GWT.log("Value is now: " + d.toString());
```

This will print the number: `10152826455075088`

This is an ID retrieved from facebook and atm I'm storing it as Long, but if this is a limitation I have to start storing my ids as Strings instead.

Can someone confirm whether this is a bug or limitation? Also, if it is a bug, where do I report it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is so huge, double precision floats have higher epsilon than 1. Epsilon is what describes the distance between the current and the next possible number.

Try this in the console of your browser:

```
console.log(10152826455075087);
```

It will print 10152826455075088. JavaScript stores all numbers as double precision floats.

Comment: Thank you for confirming! I thought GWT did some magic behind the scene that stores the double as an array containing the first half and the second half so that conversion to Long was possible? :/

Comment: Don't worry about storing the ID as a String in the client side, as you won't use that ID for math. You won't try to add, subtract two IDs or multiply them, so for you they are just that: IDs, just like phone numbers.

Comment: I didn't worry about using String as IDs it was just more convenient to use Long as all my entities have Long ids (using Objectify and String won't auto-generate ids), but I will use String when storing the facebook-id in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Note that this is exactly the same behavior in Java as well - a double with too much data will lose precision. If you want something to be a Long, refer to it as a Long everywhere. GWT emulates Long correctly.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that Colin! I find it weird that their JSONNumber class that is part of the core GWT package can't really handle big Long's then, since it stores any number as a double. Should this be something that should be brought to light in an issue report or is this something they already are aware of and just ignore?